# jQuery URL actions

Tags: jquery

Hy,

i have menu like this:

```
<a href=home>Home</a>
- <a href=home/sub1>Home Sub 1</a>
- <a href=home/sub2>Home Sub 2</a>
- <a href=home/sub3>Home Sub 3</a>

<a href=garden>Garden</a>
- <a href=garden/sub1>Garden Sub 1</a>
- <a href=garden/sub2>Garden Sub 2</a>
- <a href=garden/sub3>Garden Sub 3</a>
```

Now i set the link url:

```
$.address.init(function(event) {

$('a').address(function() {return $(this).attr('href').replace(location.pathname, '');});}).change(function(event) {

  var text = (event.value == '') ? 'Home' : 
  event.pathNames[0].substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + 
  event.pathNames[0].substr(1);
  $('a').each(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('selected', $(this).text() == text);
  });
 })
```

So if i click "Home" my URL --> www.web.com/#/home and on home sub 1 --> www.web.com/#/home/sub1.

1. how to replace the unwanted "/#/"?
2. How can i read the actual url and if it matches eg: www.web.com/garden/sub1 take some action?
   I want to use this so if people come to my website with a specific link, the actual navigation point should be open.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

> You can manipulate the URL with
>   JavaScript using the
>   window.location.href property, but
>   this will trigger a page reload;
>   fortunately you can use the
>   window.location.hash property. The
>   hash property is used for fragment
>   identifiers, which are optional
>   components of URLs that came after the
>   hash character (#). The string that
>   comes after the hash character is not
>   sent to the server; therefore, the
>   browser is responsible for restoring
>   the state through client scripts, and
>   retrieving the appropriate views.
>   Because they are like normal links,
>   but within a single page, no page
>   reload occurs, and the browser behaves
>   as if you have clicked a standard
>   link, adding the URLs to the list of
>   visited URLs. This also enables
>   history navigation, bookmarking and
>   sharing URLs with other people.

Source: http://blogs.southworks.net/jdominguez/2010/02/the-single-page-interface-pattern/